# in C# Windows Form, how to send commands to a text box?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm making a typing windows program in `C#`, 
It's finally finished now, but I just need to make the user able to write and practice in `Arabic`.

In the beginning of each typing session, there will be a `Combo Box` for him to choose 
between `English` and `Arabic`,

What I want, is that if he chooses `Arabic`, I want the `typingTextBox` typing cursor to immediately switch to the right side of the screen (`RCtrl + RShift`)
and switching the typing language to Arabic (`Alt + RShift`)

How can I do that ?

Comment: Are you trying to [localize your form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.71).aspx)?

Comment: Did you try to set the `RightToLeft` property of the textbox? See How to: [Display Right-to-Left Text in Windows Forms for Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d3337xw.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: @Hans Z No, I'm just changing the input language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an event handler for [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event on your ComboBox. Inside it use:

- [RightToLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft.aspx) property of TextBox to change the cursor position.
- [InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.currentinputlanguage.aspx) static property to change the input language for your application